# joomla is the best one for big portal websites?

Tags: joomla

We want to create big portal websites for students.this site full of revenue making and students information.Joomla is the best one to create this site? and joomla is the highly security cms.please give your suggestion.this site will make hits 50,000 on one day.Tell any other cms is best one to create big portal sites.i need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Joomla is able to handle huge traffic, but you must take care any extensions you use are really well coded and performant. I mean that there are many extensions which provide really big overhead to your site and might affect performance. My advice would be to hire a really good Joomla developer to implement most of the features of your site (i.e.: Checking any extensions you want to use are ok, or developing new ones). Besides, if your site will need to handle that traffic, you should choose carefully your hosting too ( I am currently working on a site which handles between 30k and 60k visits per day, and server configuration is as important as good coding ).

I hope it helped!

By the way, I don't know much about other CMS, but I think Drupal might be more performant than Joomla, although I prefer Joomla structure and Object-Oriented features (if it hasn't changed, Drupal is primarily based on functions. Joomla is primarily based in Objects, following MVC patterns in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla is capable of handling huge traffic.  I suggest you go ahead.

Comment: thanx Omtara.Access control in joomla 1.5 its possible.client have 500 employee work on this.previllage of back end is multiple or limited

Comment: Here is a similar question on Joomla's capacity: http://lists.nyphp.org/pipermail/joomla/2007-May/000676.html